# Why python mysql connector doesn't accept the login as variable? How i can fix it?

Tags: python, mysql

For example, this works:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="myuser",
  passwd="Ewew42sdsfds??qw",
  database="mydatabase"
)
```

But if I put this into class doesn't:

```
def __init__( self, params , headless=False ):
    self.host=params["mysqlHost"],
    self.user=params["mysqlUser"],
    self.passwd=params["mysqlPasswd"],
    self.database=params["mysqlDatabase"]

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host=self.host,
      user=self.user,
      passwd=self.passwd,
      database=self.database
    )
```

I've got an error: 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 497, in set_login
    self._user = username.strip()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

I tried to cast to a string, also I tired modify like this:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(self.host,self.user,self.passwd,self.database)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Remove the commas at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what was the real problem, but I modified my code and working well.

```
config = {
      'user': params["mysqlUser"],
      'password': params["mysqlPasswd"],
      'host': params["mysqlHost"],
      'database': params["mysqlDatabase"],
      'raise_on_warnings': True
    }



    self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like params["mysqlUser"] is a tuple and not str, and you are missing a 'self'

```
self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a comma at the end of the line when you declare the variable.